# docker percheron volumes not mounting and containers not starting

Tags: ruby, docker, percheron

I'm having trouble converting my startup bash script over to using docker [percheron](https://github.com/ashmckenzie/percheron) to monitor my containers.

Here is my start up script (which works)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Start logitech media server
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 3483:3483 -v /home/map7/data/Music/office_music:/mnt/music -v /home/map7/.logitechmediaserver:/mnt/state --name logitechmediaserver map7/logitechmediaserver

# Start a client
docker run -d --link logitechmediaserver:logitechmediaserver --privileged map7/squeezelite -n server
```

Here is my .percheron.yml file which starts but none of the volumes are mounted and the squeezelite doesn't want to start.

```
---
docker:
  host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
stacks:
  - name: lms-stack
    description: Logitech Media Server with a client on the server
    units:
      - name: logitechmediaserver
        version: 1.0.0
        docker_image: map7/logitechmediaserver
        volumes:
          - /home/map7/data/Music/office_music:/mnt/music
          - /home/map7/.logitechmediaserver:/mnt/state
        ports:
          - "9000:9000"
          - "3483:3483"
      - name: squeezelite
        version: 1.0.0
        docker_image: map7/squeezelite
        privileged: true
        needed_unit_names:
          - logitechmediaserver
```

I'm currently using ruby 2.1.5, docker 1.7.1, debian 7.8 & percheron 0.90-dev

**Update**

Also tried percheron 0.81 from rubygems